# Very small material font

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to use the material icon font in my title commands without transforming them in a FontImage but I can only obtain very little chars.

```
    Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand");
    s.setFont(FontImage.getMaterialDesignFont().derive(s.getFont().getHeight(),
Font.STYLE_PLAIN));
            UIManager.getInstance().setComponentStyle("TitleCommand", s);
```

[image: style]

this should give me the possibility to have multiple icons in a single command but the chars/glyphs I get are very small (on iphone3 simulator they are scaled to a single pixel!).

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);
Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand");
s.setFont(FontImage.getMaterialDesignFont().derive(s.getFont().getHeight(), Font.STYLE_PLAIN));
UIManager.getInstance().setComponentStyle("TitleCommand", s);
Form hi = new Form("Test");

hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar("" + FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION, null, e -> Log.p("Invoked"));

hi.show();
```

To produce this:

[image]

I usually use a more conventional way of creating an icon with a millimeter size but this should work.

Comment: shame on me! I left this "tool.findCommandComponent(back).getAllStyles().setFont(FontImage.getMaterialDesignFont());" in the bottom of my constructor and it always resets the font size. Sorry for your time...